# Adding zone affinity in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

We have a spring cloud gateway application which is deployed on two different zones. currently we have 2-2 instances for each zone. Now we wan to add zone affinity like whenever we hit request and it goes to zone 1, the proxy will send requests to the zone 1 discovery register instances only.
I have tried with @LoadBalanceClient but it doesn't work. It is working if we explicitly make a call with webclient which is annoted with @LoadBalanceClient.
For normal cloud gateway request it is using round robin load balancer and send request to both zone 1 & 2 instances.

Add zone affinity in spring cloud gateway